# Tensorflow cpu support warning

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
2020-03-05 10:31:34.823618: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2200000000 Hz
2020-03-05 10:31:34.825627: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x4c3c3a0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2020-03-05 10:31:34.825687: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
```

Help me with this warning!
I'm using TensorFlow for face detection in recorded video.

Comment: Kindly provide a reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

Does your console produce only these three messages? if yes, they are just information messages and not warnings.

We can easily distinguish them, `I` for Information, `W` for Warning and `E` for Error message.

Please refer similar question has answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61632694/13465258).