# CUPTI activity buffer flushed and GpuTracer has collected 577 callback api events and 577 activity events, should i be worried?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hope you are doing well:

Running a tensorflow code, there that in the command prompt :

```
2020-04-19 19:47:33.130484: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1378] CUPTI activity buffer flushed
2020-04-19 19:47:33.130677: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/device_tracer.cc:88]  GpuTracer has collected 577 callback api events and 577 activity events.
```

Is it problem ? Should I be worried, I use tensorflow on my GPU.

Thanks, Gabriel

Comment: Do share the code and the full trace to better understand the query. Also the versions of tensorflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are just the Information message as they are prefixed with `I`, else if it was the error message, they would be prefixed with `E` or `W` for warnings.

For Example - In the below error trace, there are some Information message prefixed with `I` and Error message prefixed with `E`.

```
2020-01-14 21:30:27.591905: I tensorflow/core/profiler/lib/profiler_session.cc:225] Profiler session started.
2020-01-14 21:30:27.594743: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1259] Profiler found 1 GPUs
2020-01-14 21:30:27.599172: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cupti64_101.dll
2020-01-14 21:30:27.704083: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1307] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
2020-01-14 21:30:27.716790: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1346] function cupti_interface_->ActivityRegisterCallbacks( AllocCuptiActivityBuffer, FreeCuptiActivityBuffer)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
Epoch 1/5
2020-01-14 21:30:28.370429: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-01-14 21:30:28.651767: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-01-14 21:30:29.662864: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1329] function cupti_interface_->EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
2020-01-14 21:30:29.670282: I tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/device_tracer.cc:88] GpuTracer has collected 0 callback api events and 0 activity events.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Gabiboubibel - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.